# syslogs on AIX machine

Tags: aix

I need to view syslog on AIX machine.
I have no clue about this.
I went through syslog.conf file and got something like this:

```
# "mail messages, at debug or higher, go to Log file. File must exist."
# "all facilities, at debug and higher, go to console"
# "all facilities, at crit or higher, go to all users"
#  mail.debug           /usr/spool/mqueue/syslog
#  *.debug              /dev/console
#  *.crit                       *
#  *.debug              /tmp/syslog.out     rotate size 100k files 4
#  *.crit               /tmp/syslog.out     rotate time 1d
```

Also,I donot know how to access /dev/console
Can somebody help out?

Answer (score 1):

See [How to configure AIX syslogd](http://ramses.smeyers.be/varia/aix/syslog/) and [managing AIX logs](http://www.softpanorama.org/Commercial_unixes/AIX/managing_aix_logs.shtml).

From your configuration, I see that all syslogged information can be found in `/tmp/syslog.out` since this is where `*.debug` is being logged.

If you don't find anything there, you should check if the `syslogd` daemon is actually running.

If you make a change to `syslog.conf` file, you have to restart the daemon using

```
refresh -s syslogd
```

**Update**: I see that everything in `syslog.conf` is commented out. If you want to see some logs, you have to enable some logging facility. For example, it should look like this:

```
# "mail messages, at debug or higher, go to Log file. File must exist."
# "all facilities, at debug and higher, go to console"
# "all facilities, at crit or higher, go to all users"
#  mail.debug           /usr/spool/mqueue/syslog
#  *.debug              /dev/console
#  *.crit                       *
*.debug              /tmp/syslog.out     rotate size 100k files 4
#  *.crit               /tmp/syslog.out     rotate time 1d
```

if you want to see anything in `/tmp/syslog.out`.

And, don't forget to restart the daemon!

**Update 2**:

To enable logging of **everything**, put this in `syslog.conf`:

```
*.*              /tmp/syslog.out     rotate size 100k files 4
```

This way you'll see if logging really is working.

Comment: I did the seeting as per you but still not able to find any file with the name syslog.out in /tmp directory.But I am able to see the logs on running the command "syslog -d"

Comment: Tried..still nothing in /tmp directory

Answer (score 1):

You forget that the file must exist:

```
touch /tmp/syslog.out

refresh -s syslogd
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `/dev/console` is the *console*, a (almost certainly) physical terminal connected to the box itself. It's not a storage device that you can get the information back from.

As to which file you need to look at, it's usually controlled by that file you showed us and individual messages can be sent to different places based on the facility and priority. However, since all those lines you see are commented out, they'll go to the default, which is probably the console.